# How to get value from URL using Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get the token value from the following URL `http://localhost:3000/users/reset/e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8`. I have a get request that checks if the token is valid and redirects the user to a reset password screen. I also have a post request but when I console `req.params.token`, it outputs `:token` instead of `e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8`. I am wondering if the form action is correct but don't know how to get the token value from it.

**Reset Password Get Request**

```
router.get('/reset/:token', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.token) // e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8
  User.findOne({
    resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
    resetPasswordExpires: {
      $gt: Date.now() 
    }
  }, (err, user) => {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error_msg', 'The password reset token is invalid or has expired.')
      return res.redirect('/users/forgot')
    }
    res.render('reset')
  })
})
```

**reset.ejs**

```
<% include ./partials/messages %>
<form action="/users/reset/:token" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter a password."
        value="<%= typeof password != 'undefined' ? password : '' %>" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
</form>
```

**Reset Password Post Request**

```
router.post('/reset/:token', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.token) // :token
  User.findOne({
    resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
    resetPasswordExpires: {
      $gt: Date.now() 
    }
  }, (err, user) => {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error_msg', 'The password reset token is invalid or has expired.')
      return res.redirect('/users/forgot')
    }

    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

    user.save(function (err) {
      req.flash('success_msg', 'Working.')
      return res.redirect('/users/login')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: What are you expecting `action="/users/reset/:token"` to do in your form post url?  It's going to literally just send that as the URL with `:token` in the URL (well the `:` will be encoded, but you get the idea).

Comment: @jfriend00 From the `http://localhost:3000/users/reset/e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8`, I am trying to get  `e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8` from the string

Comment: But, that's NOT the URL for the form post which is where you said the problem was.  It already works for the GET URL because the URL is correct.  That's the point of my comment about the form post URL.  Your form POST has `:token` in the URL, not the `e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8 ` you want.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, correct, but this token changes and expires after 60 minutes so I can't hard code the value in. I have to get it some way else. Using `req.params.token` works with the get request but not the post request

Comment: If you want it to be in the form post URL,  you HAVE to put the token in the form post URL in your page.  There is no other way for it to magically appear in the URL.  You're putting it IN the URL for the GET, but not the POST> 
 Depending upon what you're really doing here, there are other places to put the token such as in a form field, in the server-side session object for that user, etc...

Comment: In the POST code above, I have it `router.post('/reset/:token', (req, res)` @jfriend00. Can you edit the code above to show me because I don't quite understand

Comment: The `app.post()` is fine.  It is the URL in your form action in your web page that is wrong.  If you want the token to be in the post URL, you HAVE to put it into the form tag itself like `action="/users/reset/e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8"`.  Then, it would show up as `req.params.token` in the `app.post()`.  It appears you don't understand that `req.params.token` is just parsing something out of a particular position in the URL.  The desired value HAS to be in the URL before it will work

Comment: Okay thanks @jfriend00

Answer (score 2):

In your form in your HTML, you have this:

```
<form action="/users/reset/:token" method="POST">
```

That's going to make the actual URL that gets requested when the form is posted be:

```
/users/reset/:token
```

There's no code doing any substitution for the `:token` here.  That's just getting sent directly to the server as the URL.

So, when you then have:

```
router.post('/reset/:token', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);            // "/user/reset/:token"
    console.log(req.params.token);   // ":token"
});
```

What `req.params.token` is showing you is whatever is in the URL that's after `/users/reset`.  In your case, that is the literal string `":token"`.  For `req.params.token` to actually have to token in it, you would have to insert the actual token into the URL so your form tag looks like this:

```
<form action="/users/reset/e3b40d3e3550b35bc916a361d8487aefa30147c8" method="POST">
```

Or, you will have to get access to the token some other way such as from the express session, from a cookie, from a field in the form, etc...

Answer (score 0):

To get a URL parameter's value

```
app.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
    res.send("token is " + req.params.token);
});
```

To get a query parameter ?token=Adhgd5645

```
app.get('/reset/?token=Adhgd5645', function(req, res) {
    res.send("token is " + req.query.token);
});
```